# Checking for HTML Object in Safari

Tags: html

When I check a form objects element in IE it returns as an object.

When I check in Safari it doesn't see it as an object. It shows it as a HTMLInputElement.

The check I run is to check if it is an object and not null. What check would I need to run in Safari to verify it is valid

```
if ( (typeof(objForm["txtlastactionend"])=='object') 
     && ( objForm["txtlastactionend"]!=null) ){
```

Comment: How exactly are you "checking"?

Comment: if ( (typeof(objForm["txtlastactionend"])=='object') && ( objForm["txtlastactionend"]!=null) )

Comment: Which "check" are you running? Share it with us

Comment: The code thatI posted that checks typeof for object and checks that it isn't null. It works in IE,Firefox and Chrome but not Safari

Comment: That second check is not necessary because typeof returns null if the object is null.

Comment: But this check will fail in Safari since it isn't an object. It is an HTMLInputElement. How do I check for that?

Answer (score 1):

> The check I run is to check if it is an object and not null.

Why so complicated?

```
if(objForm["txtlastactionend"]) { … }
```

should do basically the same under normal conditions.

> What check would I need to run in Safari to verify it is valid

If you want to make sure you have an input field, you could check for it’s `form` property:

```
if(objForm["txtlastactionend"] && objForm["txtlastactionend"].form) { … }
```

(And maybe for a given `type` as well, depending on how specific you want to get.)